aiohttp will not serve static files, client getting "Empty reply from server"
I'm facing a weird issue where aiohttp seems to work fine aside from actually serving any static files.
I'm testing with curl, and I'm getting "Empty reply from server" when I'm trying to get to a file.
When the static route is configured with show_index=True I'm able to browse the directory where the file is located, and the file itself is being displayed in the list, yet clicking on the file will result in the same problem.
I've poked around and found that starting the aiohttp server in its own process (via ProcessPoolExecuter) fixes the issue, but for the life of me I couldn't figure out why.
The code is mostly around here.

I have no idea what's happening there (you'd have to provide a simple reproducer), but I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be using follow_symlinks=True, this may create a serious vulnerability in your project.
